# long response output in terminal shortens and changes to <…> in vscode and android studio

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.0

I have been facing a problem when I print a long response token, specially (Bearer), it shortens and the last characters or numbers will be <…>.
please help me out to get the Long Authorization Bearer response token.

[image]